# How to use Node.js efficiency in existing java web application

Tags: java, node.js, jsf, jboss

I have an existing eCommerce web application in  JSF 1.2 framework . We wish to use node.js technology's benefits in our existing application .

Our Focus : Keep View[html ] part in JSF framwork and All I/O [Database-MySql] operation will be managed by node.js .

We can do  CRUD operation using Node.js  . But how do  we send/receive  data between  java-managed-Bean and node.js ?

Is this  architecture  useful ? or any other better options/suggestion  ? .Or do we need to completely switch to Node.js technology stack ..

With regards,
Sijo

Comment: Which benefits of node.js do you want to use? I am sure you can find java solutions for all features of node.js.

Comment: Correct me if am wrong. JSF in JBOSS use one thread per request . So doing CRUD in NODE.js re-leave thread from I/O and this leads to  each thread to  become faster .   Another required feature : provide some realtime update of stocks and price .I request your expert opinion ?

Comment: First, eavaluate how many simultaneous requsts you want to process.  Take into account database throughput. If the result is >1000 requests per second (do you really have such a performant database?), then use async network library like Netty, otherwise a thread per request is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is a good idea. If you absolutely want to use node.js, you should implement your presentation layer with node and keep the crud operations in java and communicate via json. node.js is only faster if you have small operations per callback, e.g. return cached html, json etc. If you have a lot of crud operations node.js is not particularly well suited for the task. You could also take a look at the play framework http://www.playframework.com/.
It is a high performance asynchronous java / scala framework that may fit your needs.

Comment: Dear rawphl , does we have  any  stable MVC framework for building view part ?. I need to follow strict MVC pattern due to complexity of E-commerce application .One more thing if we are using Node.js in View part which java framework is good for back-end processing ? What do you think about JSP servlet, [ one request-one thread style ]

Comment: It's hard to give a general answer without knowing what you are trying to do, but let's just say since I know the play framework, I hate doing web development with anything else ;) play is fully mvc and compatible with all existing java frameworks and has a very nice template engine for serverside view rendering that is a million times better than jsp. Plus it's architecture is fully asynchronous, which means it provides high performance and scalability. If you want clientside view rendering, there are a lot of javascript mvc frameworks like backbone.js or angular.js.

Comment: ..For backend processing, Hibernate is pretty common in the java world, but as I said, without knowing what you are trying to achieve it's hard to give a good answer.

Comment: Thank you dear rawphl.. We focus on two thing 1: Real time notification and Update of stocks and price  2: If efficient perform CRUD operation in Node. But after some browsing and from your replay am feeling that Node.js is not good at CRUD operation .So  presently focus on First thing . Is this possible in JSF View layer ? How node  communicate with backend managed bean ? Am Doing some real -time operation using socket.io -event emit and recieve mechanism. Is it good to rely on this socket.io for all real-time update of enterprise system . Please feel free to correct me if am wrong